# Why do characters sometimes appear to die from nothing?

Tags: diablo-iii

This 60 level wizard seems to drop dead in the middle of the desert for no good reason. What caused this?

!

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too localize due to this being a bug that will likely get fixed fairly soon. What happens is when the sand wasps shoot their little wasps, if they're on screen, and then you move them off screen, when they come back on screen (either due to you walking towards them, or them flying onto your screen) they will be invisible. So the wiz actually got hit by 4-5 of those little wasps (which hurt a tonne).

Comment: Not to mention that this bug is now fixed as of 1.03.

Comment: Voting to reopen based on the qualifications for "technical support" (including reproducable bugs) listed [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4803/2578).  The question definitely needs a better title, though.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The bug was fixed, so this question is no longer relevant.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - The fact the death was from invisible wasps is actually part of the answer, not the question. But I don't mind the edit.

Comment: @ripper: You can see the explosion from the bugs when it happens to you (which I know from personal experience :|).  You just can't see the bugs themselves.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bug. When the wasps shoot projectiles at the edge of the screen and you move so that they disappear from your view, they will become invisible. But they can still kill you.

Here's a [thread](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4714601449) about it on the Diablo 3 Hardcore forums. The author of that thread also linked to a video where you can clearly see the bug (he tested this on SC):

**Update as of Patch 1.0.3:**

According to the [1.0.3 patch notes for Diablo 3](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6457499/Patch_103_Now_Available-6_19_2012#blog), this issue has been fixed:

> Fixed a bug where Sandwasp projectiles could sometimes become invisible.

Comment: LOL! It's a **BUG** :)

Comment: Bugs are bugged indeed.